# Is there a way to track which Sub have been run

Tags: vba, excel

This is more of a theoretical question than anything else, which if possible I may have a use for.

I was looking on the internet and found  nothing about this.

Is there a way for excel to track what Sub have been run, and then use this information within an `if` statement?

I.e.

Lets say we have Sub 1, Sub 2, Sub 3, Sub 4 & Sub 5

The sub calls next sub dependant on results. I need many subs as the use will involve UserForms as well as modules.

If

Sub 1 -> Sub 2 -> Sub 3 -> Sub 5

But Sub 5 wont run if Sub 3 has been called.

So

Sub 1 -> Sub 2 -> Sub 4 -> Sub 5 - but now sub 5 runs.

Does that make sense/ is that possible (Do I need a more powerful language?)?

Comment: I would not recommend it, but you could use a public variable and insert different values into as an array. then save that information a sheet somewhere.

Comment: As far as I know nothing like this exists in VBA and might be a little messy to do in Excel.  With Access I've done similar-ish things by creating a log table that gets populated by another subroutine that you've placed inside of all the other subroutines.  Once all that is done you could call a main subroutine that contains all your other subroutines with your intended If Then logic referencing the log table.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, it was a stab in the dark. I was trying to save myself time from recreating userforms and the just direct them to a new based upon previous choice. But thank you for confirming my theroy though :)

Comment: If you want to track which subroutine has been finished and what results has been returned, you have to change subs 2-5 into fuctions.

Comment: "track what Sub have been run, and then use this information within an if statement" sounds like a recipe for a massive spaghetti disaster. At first I thought you were looking for some logging framework ([solutions exist](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64109/23788)), but it appears you're looking for something no language I know has ever implemented, for obvious anti-spaghettification reasons. You need to separate your application logic from your logs, not intertwine them.

Comment: @Mat'sMug *no language I know has ever implemented* [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute)?

Comment: @JohnyL `CallerMemberName` tells you the name of the procedure that called the one you're in, it doesn't *track what procedures have been run*, and if you're using `CallerMemberName` for branching logic, I'm not touching your code base with a 10-foot pole.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I ain't use it (except for `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface). The question was to get the name of the caller. You insist no language has implemented such feature. So, am I wrong? :)

Comment: @JohnyL looks like you and I aren't reading the same question. OP doesn't need to know whether `DoSomething` has been called, they need to know whether some `IsFoo` flag is set. This is rather obviously a massive X-Y problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Uh... My bad! OP needs a *chain* of callers to construct one's logic. Yes, CallerMemberName doesn't fit (but, anyway, I can't understand why OP needs such logic... Eeek!).

Comment: It's not Sub5's responsibility to know it was called by Sub3 or not, it is up to Sub3 to tell Sub5 "Hey, it is me calling you!". Golden rule: *TELL, don't ask!*

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. By the sounds of it, it sounds as its possible to do but requires some clever solution. Looks like today and so on may be re writting the code :) Thanks for all of your feedback, much appricated.

Comment: Added a fully workable solution based on tracking the relevant subs (sub1 to sub4) by a `track` procedure (includes strict order check or alternative check for any order). You can easily adapt the wanted sequence of subs (up to 9) by defining a constant string code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach via log variable `State`**

Just showing you a workable approach using a `Type` variable to store a tracking code in a log variable. I'd suggest to declare it as public type pattern "TLog" in an extra code module, e.g. "modGlobals".

**Declaration head in extra module with global variables**

```
   Option Explicit
   Public Type TLog                   ' <~~  declare Public Type TLog e.g. in module 'modGlobals'
          nTimes As Integer
          State  As String
   End Type
```

**Declaration head in code module**

Here you can define your own log book, e.g. `log1` based on the `TLog` Type.
Furthermore you add a constant code string "124" defining the subsequent subs (sub1 + sub2 + sub4) that trigger sub5.

```
Option Explicit                         ' declaration head in your code module
Dim log1 As TLog                        ' module log book comprising state code and times executed
Const MYCOND As String = "124"          ' code string for condition: sub1 + sub2 +  sub4
```

**Method**

Any procedure call runs a user defined track procedure with three main tasks:

- (1) add a procedure code to the log variable (e.g. `log1.State`)
- (2) check the Subs condition "124" (sub1 + sub2 + sub4)
- (3) run sub5 if the procedure order sub1+sub2+sub4 is observed.

(Caveat: *if you want to log more than 9 subsequent subs you'd have to adapt the logging method joining only single digits for each sub*)

**Note**

I abstained from using (preferrable) **class methods** in order to show you the way. Sure you can find some ideas at SO.

**How to use a track procedure in the relevant subs**

Just call `Track 1`, `Track 2` and so on in any relevant procedure (tracking subs and checking for a strict order by default). I offered, however, the possibility to choose ANY order by setting its second argument to `False` .

```
Sub sub1()
    track 1
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub sub2()
    track 2
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub sub3()
    track 3
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub sub4()
    track 4
    ' ...
End Sub
Sub sub5()
    ' Purpose: run code only after sub1 + sub2 + sub4
    ' ...
    Beep
End Sub
```

**Example call**

```
Sub test()
' Purpose: Testing wanted series of procedures
sub1
sub2
sub4        ' << if modified to sub3, there will be no execution
End Sub
```

**Code example of a track procedure**

Wrote explanations into code comments:

```
Sub track(ByVal i As Integer, Optional bStrictOrder As Boolean = True)
' Purpose: track procedures sub1 to sub4 and run sub5 if the logged state string has a defined order (without sub3)
' Method:  the state code is logged in a declared TYPE variable, e.g. log1
' Extra:   an additional execution counter nTimes
' Note:    the constant string MYCOND "124" codes the sequence sub1 + sub2 + sub4
Dim bExecProc As Boolean            ' flag to procede in code
Dim yn        As VbMsgBoxResult     ' yes/no answer to messagebox question

  ' (0) log only first 4 procedures as precondition to execute sub5
    If i >= 5 Then Exit Sub             ' just in case of additional track statements in higher subs


  ' -------------------------------------------------------
  ' (1) track procedures by adding digit code to log1.State
  '     (reinitiate log1 after procedure sub1)
  ' -------------------------------------------------------
    log1.State = IIf(i = 1 And bStrictOrder, "", log1.State) & Format(i, "0")
  ' note: might demand further code to avoid subsequent calls of the same procedure 
  ' 
  ' -------------------------------------------
  '  (2) Check defined condition code
  ' -------------------------------------------
  If bStrictOrder Then
  '  (2a) sub1 + sub2 + sub4 have run before in defined ORDER
          If log1.State = MYCOND Then bExecProc = True
  Else
  '  (2b) alternative: sub1, sub2 and sub4 have run in ANY order
          If Arrange(log1.State) = MYCOND Then bExecProc = True
  End If

  ' -------------------------------------------
  '  (3) Execute procedure sub5
  ' -------------------------------------------
    If bExecProc Then
    ' optional security message if sub5 has been already executed before
      If log1.nTimes = 0 Then
       yn = vbYes
      Else
       yn = MsgBox("Sub5 has been executed already " & log1.nTimes & " time(s). " & _
            "Do you want to procede?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Attention")
      End If
      If yn = vbYes Then
      ' do it and reset state and execution counter
        MsgBox "I'm calling sub5 now" & vbNewLine & " because " & vbNewLine & _
             " log1.State code shows """ & log1.State & """" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             " (log1.nTimes = " & log1.nTimes & " time(s) up till now)", vbInformation, "Just before running Sub5"
      ' ~~~~~~
        sub5                             ' <~~ execute procedure sub5
      ' ~~~~~~
        log1.State = ""                  ' reset state
        log1.nTimes = log1.nTimes + 1    ' increment execution counter
      End If

    End If


End Sub
```

**Helper Function in case of ANY order of procedures**

The helper function `Arrange()` is only used if you would set the 2nd (optional) argument of all your `Track` calls to `False`, e.g. `Track 1, False`.

```
Function Arrange(ByVal s As String) As String
' Purpose: Helper function to rearrange State code for logging (e.g. log1.State)
' caveat:  limited to 9 subsequent subs with single digits
' Note:    (admittedly code could be refined)
  Dim i As Integer       ' counter
  ReDim v(1 To Len(s))
  Dim d As Integer       ' each digit in code s
' loop through State code characters so far
  For i = 1 To Len(s)
      v(i) = Val(Mid(s, i, 1))
  Next i
  SortAr v
' return rearranged code string
  Arrange = Join(v, "")
End Function

Sub SortAr(arr())
' Purpose:  sort one based 1-dim array
' cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721489/how-can-i-sort-dates-in-an-array-in-vba
Dim Temp
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Temp = arr(j)
    For i = j - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If (arr(i) <= Temp) Then GoTo 10
            arr(i + 1) = arr(i)
    Next i
    i = 0
10:     arr(i + 1) = Temp
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I shall have a look through this and try to makes heads and tails of it. I may pop back up and ask Q's if that is ok?

Comment: Having read throuigh this in more detial, this has to be one of the most comprenshive and detailed answers I've ever seen. Its just incrediable

Comment: When i try and call this module `Sub LogTest (ByVal i as Integer, Optional bStrictOrder as Boolean = true)` i get a Argument Not Optional error. I am right in thinking this is down to `Optiional bStrictOrder as Boolean`? or not? Thanks

Comment: Suppose this to refer to the 1st argument as only the 2nd is optional. Possibly you called your test procedure without any argument like `LogTest` only instead of e.g. `LogTest 1` or `LogTest 1, True` (cf. `track {n}` in my answer).

Answer (score 3):

You basically want to create a state engine in your module/project. This state engine would be at the global level, and each function/sub-routine would change the state when run.

I would consider that each function/routine should fire an event when entering and leaving. Your state machine would listen for each event and modify the state accordingly.

If you have functions/routines that are dependent on particular states before proceeding, then add additional code to query the current state. Another way to tackle this is to have the state query occur before trying to fire the function/sub-routine. Depends on what you want you code to do and how you want it to respond when trying to do invalid code branches.

Comment: A state engine being another Function/Sub etc. with loads of different If Then rules to satistfy what i need? Have i understood that right?

Comment: My initial concept is global variables (or perhaps a single variable or class/structure) to contain the state information and event handlers to change these global variables. So, the short answer is that the state engine is not another function/sub. A function/sub would be "blocking" or interrupting your normal flow of code, and I don't think you want this. How you set up the global variables/structure/class will depend on what state information you want to keep. But choose the most efficient way for you to store, modify and access that information when required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it! Follow these steps:

1. create one procedure (subroutine)
2. create 4 functions which returns true/false values (depednding on what result you want to get)
3. inside a procedure you can use function like a variable

For example:

```
 Sub TrackSubroutines
     If Function1(parameters) Then
        If Functions2(parameters) Then
    '... and so on
        End If
     End If
 End Sub

Function1(parameters) As Boolean
    Function1 = True/False
End Function

Function2(parameters) As Boolean
    Function1 = True/False
End Function
```

More you'll find at MSDN: [Calling Sub and Function Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/calling-sub-and-function-procedures)