# Listbox sort/filter by date time in vba userform?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform with a listbox that displays data from a worksheet. I am wanting to get that data to display in the listbox by current date and time. So when a user enters new data he/she sees the most current lines of data. This is to help the user so they don't enter duplicate information.

I am hoping this can be accomplished programmatically because in the near future this form will be linked to a database not a worksheet.

Here is the code to populate my listbox:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'Sets variables when the userform initializes

    Call MakeFormResizeable(Me)

    Me.tbDate.Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")

     With ListBox1
        .RowSource = "Table1!A3:T100"
        .ColumnCount = 20
        .ColumnHeads = True
    End With
   End Sub
```

And the code to reload my listbox when the save button is clicked by calling "RefreshListbox" :

```
   Private Sub RefreshListbox()
       With ListBox1
         .RowSource = "Table1!A3:T100"
         .ColumnCount = 20
         .ColumnHeads = True
      End With
   End Sub
```

Screen shot of my userform:
[UserForm Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUmzk.jpg)

Comment: sort the table by the column you want and the listbox should load accordingly. If that is not an option, you'll have to create a separate place to store the sorted data before loading to the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred to [Date Array Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20725290/9808063) and 
[Populating listbox from array](https://youtu.be/jG-YJQwhg54)

Public declaration of an array variable in a module
`Public Dtarr(1 To 8) As Date`
One can redim the array size in a macro to resize it to the table size.

Following is the dates table
[image]

Added following procedure in a module to sort a date array.

```
Sub SortAr(arr() As Date)
    Dim Temp As Date
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
        Temp = arr(j)
        For i = j - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If (arr(i) >= Temp) Then GoTo 10
' ">" sorts in descending order.
' "<" sorts in ascending order.
                arr(i + 1) = arr(i)
        Next i
        i = 0
10:         arr(i + 1) = Temp
    Next j
End Sub
```

Added following procedure to the userform

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

For i = 1 To 8
Dtarr(i) = Sh.Range("A" & i + 3).Value
Next

SortAr Dtarr
ListBox1.List = Dtarr

End Sub
```

So, the output is the descending order sorted listbox. The user can always see the latest record time at the top.

[image]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Editing answer as per your comment below

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Following is the sample data in A1:T13.

[image]

Following is userform code. You can specify the data range (`arrData`) in the userform code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set Sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set AllData = Sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
x = AllData.Rows.Count - 1: y = AllData.Columns.Count
Set ListData = AllData.Offset(1, 0).Resize(x, y)

ReDim Dtarr(1 To x, 1 To y)
Dtarr = ListData.Value

Sort2DArr Dtarr, 2 'Second column as you need to sort on Column B

With ListBox1
    .List = Dtarr
    .ColumnCount = y
    .ColumnWidths = "25;100;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25;25"
End With
End Sub
```

Following is Module1 code to sort the Dtarr. Please note `Public Dtarr()` in the code

```
Option Base 1
Public Sh As Worksheet
Public AllData As Range
Public ListData As Range
Public x As Long
Public y As Long
Public Dtarr()



Sub Sort2DArr(arr(), srtCol As Long)

Dim temp As Date, temparr, srtColArr, temp2 As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

ReDim temparr(x)
srtColArr = WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, srtCol)
For i = 1 To x
    temparr(i) = Join(Application.Index(arr, i, 0), "~")
Next

temparr = Application.Transpose(temparr)

For j = 2 To x
    temp = srtColArr(j, 1)
    temp2 = temparr(j, 1)
    For i = j - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If (srtColArr(i, 1) >= temp) Then GoTo 10
        ' ">" sorts in descending order.
        ' "<" sorts in ascending order.
        srtColArr(i + 1, 1) = srtColArr(i, 1)
        temparr(i + 1, 1) = temparr(i, 1)
    Next i
        i = 0
10:     srtColArr(i + 1, 1) = temp
        temparr(i + 1, 1) = temp2
    Next j

ReDim Dtarr(1 To x + 1, 1 To y)

For i = 1 To y
    Dtarr(1, i) = AllData(1, i).Value
Next
For i = 2 To x + 1
    tempRow = Split(temparr(i - 1, 1), "~")
    For j = 1 To y
    Dtarr(i, j) = tempRow(j - 1)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

So, the output is the descending order sorted listbox. The user can always see the latest record time at the top.

[image]

Comment: Compile Error: Sub of function not defined.

Comment: Error at which line? ... Have you copied the SortAr procedure in a module ?

Comment: Yes, i did past into module. The Error is at "Dtarr(i) =".

Comment: Maybe someone else has a suggestion or solution?

Comment: please accept apologies for delayed response. Working on this. Data is A3:T100, Hence, we need a 2D array sort.  My answer in inadequate as it sorts only data time column. Meanwhile I would suggest to edit your question with a screenshot of the data sheet.(A3:T100). This will make the question active again and will seek more attention from others as well.

Comment: Answer edited please check ... Also, If you dont intend to use Sort2DArr for a purpose other than for lisbox sort, you can put it in userform as `private sub` .... If this answers your question please tick / upvote/ accept the answer.

Comment: Im getting a runtime error 13 'type mismatch' I cannot  figure out why. Unless the fact that some of my data is text?

Comment: See the edited answer now,. Note the public variables in the module

Comment: Worked perfectly! Brilliant!