# Sorting dates using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data displayed on a listbox, after clicking on a button the list appears on my userform.
I have dates on column 2 of my list, I want to do a descending sorting.
I have the code bellow but it's not working, am I wrong ?

```
    fin_col_Form_Init = Ws.Cells(6, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnCount = 2
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnWidths = "300;100"
    fin_col_Form_Init = Ws.Cells(6, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnCount = 2
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnWidths = "300;100"

For i = 2 To fin_col_Form_Init
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.AddItem Ws.Cells(6, i)
UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List(UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ListCount - 1, 1) = Ws.Cells(7, i)
Next i

    Dim y, x As Integer
    Dim MyList As Variant
    
        With UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init
            For y = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                For x = y To .ListCount - 1
                    If CDate(.List(x, 1)) > CDate(.List(y, 1)) Then
                        For c = 0 To 2
                            MyList = .List(x, c)
                            .List(x, c) = .List(y, c)
                            .List(y, c) = MyList
                        Next c
                    End If
                Next x
    
            .List(y, 2) = Format(.List(y, 2), "####.00")
            Next y
        End With
```

Comment: a) Please describe "not working" - b) Did you step through your code in the debugger and look at the steps it takes and the values of the variables? What did you learn, where does your code go wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530566/listbox-sort-filter-by-date-time-in-vba-userform

Comment: You should extract an array from the list, sort the array and then loading back the listbox using it (sorted)...

Comment: @braX well with the code I wrote it only displays the list of elements without sorting them, it's like the sorting code doesn't exsit

Comment: @braX my code is working, I've just noticed that I have put the code on the wrong place (before loading my data) it's obviously that the code want to do the sorting if there's no data on the list. My bad. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testSortListBox()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, sTemp As Date, sTemp2 As String, SortList As Variant
    
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnCount = 2
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.ColumnWidths = "300;100"

    'Store the list in an array to be sorted:
    SortList = UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List
    
    'Sort the array on the second column
    For i = LBound(SortList, 1) To UBound(SortList, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(SortList, 1)
            If CDate(SortList(i, 1)) < CDate(SortList(j, 1)) Then
                'Swap the second value
                sTemp = SortList(i, 1)
                SortList(i, 1) = SortList(j, 1)
                SortList(j, 1) = sTemp
                
                'Swap the first value
                sTemp2 = SortList(i, 0)
                SortList(i, 0) = SortList(j, 0)
                SortList(j, 0) = sTemp2
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Remove the contents of the listbox:
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.Clear
    'Load the sorted array in the list box:
    UF_Profil_Edit1.ListBox_Form_Init.List = SortList
End Sub
```

But, please note: The list box in discussion must not be linked to a range (not being load by its `RowSource` property...

Comment: I tried your code, the listbox is empty, I have nothing on mylist.

Comment: But, what are you trying to sort? Don't you have a list box (`ListBox_Form_Init`), which "appears on your userform"? What do you mean? The list is filled and after sorting using my above code, it appears being empty?

Comment: It's working now, sorry Im a bit tired I've copied the code on the wrong place, it should be added after loading the list with data I have put the code before loading my data, now it's working. Thank you very much.

Comment: @IMP_Te: So, does it answer your question? If yes, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...