# Rank items in a listbox sequentially by current date

Tags: excel, vba

maybe it sounds like an easy question for you but I'm struggling

I want to rank my items from a Worksheet in Excel in a Userform Listbox. So that the current item in the listox is in the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530566/listbox-sort-filter-by-date-time-in-vba-userform

Comment: Can you sort them before you load it? That's probably the easiest way.

Comment: @brax thank you for the link. I'm not sure about this kind of solution because the items are "ranked" but I want the current date on top of the list and see if I want the previous dates bevor.

Yes - I think now the Spreadsheet Version is the easiest way..

Comment: You can load the range into an array, sort the array, and then use the array to populate the list box...