# How to show the last 10 entries in listbox made VBA

Tags: excel, vba, forms, sorting, data-entry

It seems that sorting in descending form in listbox VBA is a little bit hard like my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982481/excel-form-listbox-vba-how-to-sort-last-date-and-time-entry) here. Is there any way I can display the last 10 entries made in listbox? I keep scrolling down to see the last 10 entries at the bottom of the listbox. Attached are the images of the code and the form. Please understand that I am using mobile to capture it because transferring data from my laptop is restricted.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim Row As Long
 Row = [Counta(ExcelEntryDB!A:E)]
 Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
 Me.ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
 Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "75;75;75"

 If Row > 1 Then
  Me.ListBox1.Rowsource = "ExcelEntryDB!C2:E" & Row
 Else
  Me.ListBox1.Rowsource = "ExcelEntryDB!C2:E2" & Row
 End If

 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = 
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExcelEntryDB")
 Dim n As Long

 n = sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
   sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Format(Time, "hh:nn:ss" AM/PM)
   sh.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value

 Me.TextBox3.Value = ""

End Sub
```

[image: code]

[image: form]

[SOLVED] BIG THANKS TO taller_ExcelHome

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExcelEntryDB")

Dim n As Long

n = sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    sh.Range("D" & n + 1).Value = Format(Time, "hh:nn:ss AM/PM")

    sh.Range("E" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtColor.Value

    sh.Range("G" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtName.Value

    sh.Range("H" & n + 1).Value = Me.txtShape.Value

Me.txtName.Value = ""

Me.txtColor.Value = ""

Me.txtShape.Value = ""

Call arrayR

End Sub

Sub arrayR()

   Dim arr(), lastRow As Long, i As Integer 'get last column number using index

    With ActiveSheet

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim arr(IIf(lastRow > 20, 20, lastRow - 1), 5)

arr(0, 0) = .Cells(1, 3)

arr(0, 1) = .Cells(1, 4)

arr(0, 2) = .Cells(1, 5)

arr(0, 4) = .Cells(1, 7)

arr(0, 5) = .Cells(1, 8)

    If lastRow > 20 Then

        For i = 1 To 20

            arr(i, 0) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 3).Text

            arr(i, 1) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 4).Text

            arr(i, 2) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 5).Text

            arr(i, 4) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 7).Text

            arr(i, 5) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 8).Text

        Next

    Else

        For i = 1 To lastRow - 1

            arr(i, 0) = .Cells(i + 1, 3).Text

            arr(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 4).Text

            arr(i, 2) = .Cells(i + 1, 5).Text

            arr(i, 4) = .Cells(i + 1, 7).Text

            arr(i, 5) = .Cells(lastRow - 20 + i, 8).Text

        Next

    End If

End With

With Me.ListBox1

.ColumnHeads = True

.ColumnCount = 6

.ColumnWidths = "75,75,75,75,75,75"

.List = arr()

End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

arrayR

End Sub
```

[image: updated image]

Comment: okay i will be typing it in my mobile now. laptop is not allowed to use during not work hours

Comment: You should calculate `Row` in exactly the same way you calculated `n`. `Row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExcelEntryDb").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`. `CountA` will give you way more rows than you want.

Comment: yes thanks for the tip. it did shorten the rows. wishing for the last 10 entries to display in listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution close to your needs, with some differences:

- Listbox column headers can't set by `.List` property.
- `.RowSource` uses header row which is next to the data range (RowSource). You can't get the correct header if using last 10 rows as RowSource.
- First row in listbox becomes a "header" but is also selectable, requiring exception handling in your code

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arr(10, 1), lastRow As Long, i As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        arr(0, 0) = .Cells(1, 3)
        arr(0, 1) = .Cells(1, 4)
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow > 10 Then
            For i = 1 To 10
                arr(i, 0) = .Cells(lastRow - 10 + i, 3).Text
                arr(i, 1) = .Cells(lastRow - 10 + i, 4).Text
            Next
        Else
            For i = 1 To lastRow - 1
                arr(i, 0) = .Cells(i + 1, 3).Text
                arr(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 4).Text
            Next
        End If
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "75;75"
        .List = arr()
    End With
End Sub
```

> Updated code to load 3 columns in Listbox.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arr(), lastRow As Long, i As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim arr(IIf(lastRow > 10, 10, lastRow - 1), 2)
        arr(0, 0) = .Cells(1, 3)
        arr(0, 1) = .Cells(1, 4)
        arr(0, 2) = .Cells(1, 5)
        If lastRow > 10 Then
            For i = 1 To 10
                arr(i, 0) = .Cells(lastRow - 10 + i, 3).Text
                arr(i, 1) = .Cells(lastRow - 10 + i, 4).Text
                arr(i, 2) = .Cells(lastRow - 10 + i, 5).Text
            Next
        Else
            For i = 1 To lastRow - 1
                arr(i, 0) = .Cells(i + 1, 3).Text
                arr(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 4).Text
                arr(i, 2) = .Cells(i + 1, 5).Text
            Next
        End If
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "75;75;75"
        .List = arr()
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

> Alternative is a `Label` above listbox for static header

[image]

> Loading Listbox rows via `.List` allows flexibility like reversing order. The last row (row 14 in the first screenshot) can be shown first.

[image]

---

Spare columns (i.e column AA and AB) to store listbox data allows implementing the exactly desired listbox behavior. Spare columns could be cleaned in `UserForm_Terminate()` event.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("AA:AB").Clear
        .Range("AB:AB").NumberFormatLocal = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Range("AA:AA").NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy"
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        .[aa1].Resize(1, 2).Value = .Range("C1:D1").Value
        If lastRow > 10 Then '*
            .[aa2].Resize(10, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(lastRow - 9, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 4)).Value '*
        Else '*
            .[aa2].Resize(lastRow - 1, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 4)).Value '*
        End If '*
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "75;75"
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "AA2:AB" & lastRow
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> Loading three columns, updated code are mark with "'*"

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("AA:AC").Clear '*
        .Range("AB:AB").NumberFormatLocal = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        .Range("AA:AA").NumberFormatLocal = "m/d/yyyy"
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row '*
        .[aa1].Resize(1, 3).Value = .Range("C1:E1").Value '*
        If lastRow > 10 Then '*
            .[aa2].Resize(10, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(lastRow - 9, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value '*
        Else '*
            .[aa2].Resize(lastRow - 1, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value '*
        End If '*
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3 '*
        .ColumnWidths = "75;75;75"  '*
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = "AA2:AC" & lastRow  '*
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried to put your first code in initialize and it has an error that says type mismatch.also, your 2nd code worked but when i tried to add another column Color in sheet for the E column and a textfield to enter the color, columncount changed to 3 and columnwidths added 75 and no changes to the code for ActiveSheet (for testing purposes), the result in listbox has the correct date and time (with only 10 entries which is my needed output) but blank for the next column, no header Color too. what could i miss

Comment: So, do you only want removing the last 10 items from the list box? Is it something else from your question I missed?

Comment: I only want to display in the listbox the last 10 entries entered in the sheet for this question. Ty

Comment: I tried again the last code answeres by 'taller', it shows the exact output except that all data inputted at the top transfers to cell AA onwards

Comment: @Cecil Please clarify the final question design needs in OP. Code updated to load 3 columns as example. I can't tell your what's wrong with option 1 implementaion w/o your code. All posed code have been tested.

Comment: i tried one input. i used my code and inserted your code just above the end sub. the output is multiplying the entry 10 times with the same date and time.

Comment: It is a typo. Using `.[aa2].Resize(lastRow - 1, 3).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 5)).Value `

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome copy. i tried ur first code which has arr(10,1): everytime i try to put arr(0,2) after arr(0,1), i always get error subscript out of range. coz i want to display the color column, too and possible more columns to display in line with the date and time column. also, in the lastRow inside For, i get type mismatch error

Comment: May I know which option you are prefer to have? Are you going switch from option 2 to 1? It saves time to understand and optimize only one option.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome prefer to have the first option.cant use the last option because some of the data which i need to extract transfers to column AA onwards. the first option array (10,1) is helpful. just the errors about the ones i commented. or the .List option which i dont know yet how to display it using .List method for the last 10 entries. ty

Comment: I have updated opton 1.

Comment: i will try. brb