# ComboBox change event result in ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox

This is an updated question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252533/show-filtered-data-in-cascaded-comboboxes-and-listbox1). Answer from this post works perfectly especially for the cascaded combobox change. I am just having trouble with displaying the result in ListBox1 according to **all** that matched in Sheet1 in the last change event.

This is the raw data:

```
Col. A    Col. B   Col. G    Col. J    Col. L
YEAR    || NAME || COLOR || MONTH    || SHAPE
2023    || LINA || GREEN || AUGUST   || HEART
2023    || LINA || GREEN || SEPTEMBER|| CIRCLE
2024    || GARY || GREEN || SEPTEMBER|| DIAMOND
2024    || GARY || GREEN || SEPTEMBER|| RECTANGLE
2024    || GARY || RED   || AUGUST   || OVAL
2023    || GARY || RED   || AUGUST   || RECTANGLE
2023    || GARY || GREEN || AUGUST   || SQUARE
2024    || GARY || GREEN || SEPTEMBER|| STAR
2024    || TOM  || RED   || AUGUST   || HEART
2024    || TOM  || RED   || SEPTEMBER|| CIRCLE
2024    || TOM  || RED   || SEPTEMBER|| DIAMOND
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| SEPTEMBER|| OVAL
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| OCTOBER  || RECTANGLE
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| OCTOBER  || CIRCLE
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| OCTOBER  || SQUARE
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| OCTOBER  || STAR
2024    || TOM  || YELLOW|| OCTOBER  || STAR
2024    || TOM  || BLUE  || OCTOBER  || SQUARE
```

Image of raw data (blanks here have purpose):
[image: raw image]

Code for the change event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    If Not ComboBox4.Value = "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rcell As Range, Key
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arrData = ws.Range("A1:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        ReDim arrList(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrList(1, j) = arrData(1, j)
        Next
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value And arrData(i, 1) = CStr(ComboBox2.Value) _
                And arrData(i, 7) = ComboBox3.Value And arrData(i, 10) = ComboBox4.Value Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrList(2, j) = arrData(i, j)
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        
        Next
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "35,35,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,50,0,50"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = arrList
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, using the change event code above returns 1 row of data only (if I choose Tom in 2024 with Yellow color and October month) when it should return more rows to display in ListBox1 because it has more than one shape (it is fine if shape is repeating in Sheet1):
[image: listbox displays one row only]

My desired output is this (when manually filtered in Sheet1):
[image: desired output]

What should be changed in the change event code to correct this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    If Not ComboBox4.value = "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, count As Long, K As Long
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:L" & ws.cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        arrData = rng.value

        'determine the necessary number of final array rows:
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng.Columns(1), CStr(ComboBox2.value), rng.Columns(2), ComboBox1.value, rng.Columns(7), ComboBox3.value, rng.Columns(10), ComboBox4.value)
        ReDim arrList(1 To count + 1, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrList(1, j) = arrData(1, j) 'the header
        Next
        K = 1
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = ComboBox1.value And arrData(i, 1) = CStr(ComboBox2.value) _
                And arrData(i, 7) = ComboBox3.value And arrData(i, 10) = ComboBox4.value Then
                K = K + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrList(K, j) = arrData(i, j) 'matching data
                Next
            End If
        
        Next
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "35,35,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,50,0,50"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = arrList
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: let me try this brb

Comment: this one made easier for me in another workbook thank you

Comment: I congratulate you on the helpful idea of **immediately** determining the *total* resulting number of row elements using the **`CountIfs`** function. This allows the array to be correctly dimensioned immediately in the 1st dimension, without a subsequent `ReDim` and the need to transpose columns and rows twice +:) @FaneDuru

Answer (score 2):

The items count of listbox isn't fixed. Using dynamic array collects items.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
    If Not ComboBox4.Value = "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rcell As Range, iIdx As Integer
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        arrData = ws.Range("A1:L" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        ReDim Preserve arrList(1 To UBound(arrData, 2), 1 To 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            arrList(j, 1) = arrData(1, j)
        Next
        iIdx = 1
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value And arrData(i, 1) = CStr(ComboBox2.Value) _
                And arrData(i, 7) = ComboBox3.Value And arrData(i, 10) = ComboBox4.Value Then
                iIdx = iIdx + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrList(1 To UBound(arrData, 2), 1 To iIdx)
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrList(j, iIdx) = arrData(i, j)
                Next
            End If
        
        Next
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "35,35,0,0,0,0,40,0,0,50,0,50"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = Application.Transpose(arrList)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Too bad you can't limit what you pass to a listbox like you can with a range, i.e. `Range("A1").Resize(rCount,colCount) = arr` when arr is bigger.

Comment: let me try this brb

Comment: Allow me some hints to your working code (using transposed row/column elements in `arrList`): I'd (re)dimension `arrList` first to its maximum boundaries (`ReDim Preserve arrList(1 To UBound(arrData, 2), 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)) `) and only a 2nd time outside the main loop `ReDim Preserve arrList(1 To UBound(arrData, 2), 1 To idx) `. - It might be instructive for other users, too knowing that you can avoid re-transposing via the listboxe's `.Column` property: `.Column = arrList` @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: Maybe of some interest how I came across the `.Column` property some years ago: [How to speed up filling of listbox values on UserForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983374/how-to-speed-up-filling-of-listbox-values-on-userform-excel/47003993#47003993) @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: @T.M. Thanks for your sharing. I didn't get why it is better to redim array `its maximum boundaries`.

Comment: ... in order to avoid many, many subsequent `ReDim`s within your main loop when redimming outside the loop a 2nd time @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: The `arrData` array might be large, but it's not necessary for `arrList` to be of the same size.

Comment: The 1st  `arrList` redimming (btw no need of `Preserve here`) represents only the temporary & dynamic starting provision for the hypothetical case that *all* rows meet your search conditions;  placing a 2nd ReDim **outside** the *last loop*, however reduces any further redimming(s) (`ReDim Preserve`!) to a second final `ReDim` thus minimizing execution time for larger data. @taller_ExcelHome